# How to pass to a component an attribute with variable and static parts in EmberJs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, attributes

I'm trying to pass to a link-to component a style attribute. As it's not a default attributeBinding, I had to reopen LinkComponent class and add the 'style' attribute there.

```
Ember.LinkComponent.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['style']
});
```

Doing that, now I can set something like the following:

```
{{#link-to element.link element.param style="background: red;"}}Text Link{{/link-to}}
```

It will render it properly and we will see an eye-burning link with a red background.

What I'm trying to achieve is to apply an image url as a background-image property on the style attr.

```
{{#link-to element.link element.param style="background-image: url(element.background);"}}Text Link{{/link-to}}
```

But I'm only getting the variable name inside the attribute.

I tried with:

- element.background
- ${element.background}
- {{element.background}}
- treat it like a sum of string and variable parts "url("+element.background+")" but it breaks the code compilation

I know it seems to be a computed property, and probably passing the URL and creating the whole value inside the Class, or maybe passing the value formatted on the first place with `style=element.background` could do the trick, but as it's the link-to helper I'd prefer to keep it just listening to the style attribute and the model just holding the url values.

Any help or idea would be broadly welcomed.

Comment: try `style=(concat 'background-image: url(' element.background ');')`

Comment: It's aliiiive!! Thanks a mill. Could you please write it down as an answer to mark the question as resolved and this stuff? (to give you the credit, I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` helper,

```
style=(concat 'background-image: url(' element.background ');')
```

Reference : http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat